# Use custom object in Jackson constructor

Tags: java, jackson

Is there a way to provide the Jackson Deserializer with a default value from "the outside" (e.g. DI container) that it will use when deserializing an object, in this case tagRegistry?

```
  @JsonCreator
  public ExtractionRule(@JsonProperty("id") String id, 
                        TagRegistry tagRegistry) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tagRegistry = tagRegistry;
  }
```

I couldn't find an easy way to do this.

Comment: Anything like this?

@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class CustomClass {
    ...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try @JacksonInject. Add this member to the ExtractionRule class:

```
@JacksonInject("tagRegistry")
private TagRegistry tagRegistry;
```

And inject the tagRegistry to the ObjectMapper before deserialization:

```
 InjectableValues.Std injectableValues = new InjectableValues.Std();
 injectableValues.addValue("tagRegistry", tagRegistry);

 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 objectMapper.setInjectableValues(injectableValues);
```

I haven't tried using it in a constructor, not sure if that works.
You can find further examples here:

- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/jackson-inject.html
- https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jacksoninject-example#JacksonInject